# Value in the Fragment cannot be shown

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a typo regarding getting value from bundle and show it in the Fragment.

My song class has two values title and its detail.

```
private String songTitle;
private String details;
```

After sending value from bundle in Adapter part, I get it from Detail Part by doing vice versa process. I show it via getSupportFragmentManager feature.

Although the detail page open without any problem, there is no value in Detail part.

Here is my Detail part and Fragment part.

How can I fix it?

Detail Part

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Get the selected song position from the intent extra.
            int selectedSong =
                    getIntent().getIntExtra(SongUtil.SONG_ID_KEY, 0);

            Log.i(LOG,"selectedSong : " + selectedSong);

            // Create instance of the detail fragment and add it to the activity
            // using a fragment transaction.
            SongDetailFragment fragment =
                    SongDetailFragment.newInstance(selectedSong);

            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.song_detail_container, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
```

Detail Fragment

```
public static SongDetailFragment newInstance (int selectedSong) {
        SongDetailFragment fragment = new SongDetailFragment();
        // Set the bundle arguments for the fragment.
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(SongUtil.SONG_ID_KEY, selectedSong);
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return fragment;
    }
```

Link : [Project Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/FragmentApp)

Comment: are you getting song id here? `Log.i(LOG,"selectedSong : " + selectedSong);`

Comment: @KishoreJethava I edited my post. Can you look it out?

Comment: Any reason to use `savedInstanceState`? please try after removing it.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by defined static methods for list process in which items are inserted